# Material-UI Drawer issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menuitem, material-ui, drawer

I want this drawer to stick with the page just like a sticker and be active. Everythings fine but whenever I am scrolling down, the whole drawer also moves down. How can I fix it? I don't want this whole thing to move down while scrolling.

Note: I tried to fix this thing by using docked={false}. But using it there makes the whole page inactive except the drawer.

**Encountered the same problem? Any Solution?**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

class MenuView extends Component {
 render {
  return(
   <Drawer open={true} containerStyle={{marginTop: '6.5%', background:'#545454', position:'fixed'}}>
    <MenuItem primaryText="My Name" style={{color:'white', marginTop:'10%'}} href="#/name" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
    <MenuItem primaryText="My Age" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/age" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
    <MenuItem primaryText="My Address" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/address" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
    <MenuItem primaryText="My Files" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/files" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>  
   </Drawer>
  );
 }
}
export default MenuView;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you create a jsfiddle for this so that we may have a look on it. 
OR
Try adding "Top" property of css inside containerStyle.

```html
<Drawer open={true} containerStyle={{top: '0%', background:'#545454', position:'fixed'}}>
  <MenuItem primaryText="My Name" style={{color:'white', marginTop:'10%'}} href="#/name" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
  <MenuItem primaryText="My Age" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/age" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
  <MenuItem primaryText="My Address" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/address" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
  <MenuItem primaryText="My Files" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/files" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>  
</Drawer>
```

Comment: I want the drawer to be positioned a little bit down from top so I gave the **marginTop**. There's no point of giving **top:'0%'** there.

Comment: Yes.. instead of giving marginTop: '6.5%', try to give top:'6.5%'

Comment: no difference. I just tried. It's the same as before. while scrolling down the page, the whole drawer also moves down.